# Can't find defaultResourceProxyImpl class in osmdroid 5.2

Tags: osmdroid

I want to use the DefaultResourceProxyImpl class, but it has been removed since osmdroid 5.2

Some of the code lines need this class.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please provide the code lines that request the DefaultResourceProxyImpl class.

Comment: ResourceProxy and related classes where removed in osmdroid-5.2 **Why** do you need it?

Answer (score 3):

The DefaultResourceProxyImpl class is deprecated. Bit If you want the Java file... http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=osmdroid-master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/DefaultResourceProxyImpl.java